# Format MySQL Date

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012

MySQL table contains a date format 23/11/2012 , i want to display as '23/11' in a label of visual studio, c#, how?

```
void decorator()
{
    string myConnection = "datasource= localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
    MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from bs.login where type='id'", myConn);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myConn.Open();

    string a = string.Empty;

    myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    a = myReader.GetString(1);

    label1.Text = a;// here i want dd/MM format but in table has dd/MM/yyyy format
}
```

Comment: Why does your MySQL table not just have Date values, which could be converted to DateTime when fetched with the reader? Then you can format the DateTime however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a `DateTime`, and then format it:

```
a = DateTime.Parse(myReader.GetString(1)).ToString("dd/MM");
```